# The fundamental group of the unit disc with one point removed from its boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

If $y\in \partial (\mathbb D^2)$, then how to find $\pi_1(\mathbb D^2-\{y\})$? 
I know that if $y$ was an interior point then the answer will be $\mathbb Z$. But why both cases would be similar ?

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty obvious that your space is contractible: you can deformation retract it to the centre along straight lines, say. Thus its fundamental group is trivial.

Comment: sorry, said something stupid probably - how to delete?

Comment: @Louis: Compactness is not a homotopy invariant.

Comment: Yes, I just figured this myself. Pardon me.

Comment: if you stretch the space out in every direction, you end up with the half-slit plane. it's quite intuitive that there are no non-homotopically trivial paths in this